# Magento2 does varnish cache help to improve performance on development mode?

Tags: magento2, varnish

I am working on a Magento EE project and version is 2.1.15, and since we have lots of product on the products page, and takes 22s to reload the page, so i am wondering will varnish help to improve the performance to reduce the loading time on the products page? and i tried on my Ubuntu machine and seems like not a lot of difference even i use varnish cache

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does. I have integrated Varnish in many websites and the results are impressive.
This is from their website [Varnish Website](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/tutorial/introduction.html):

> Varnish has a modern architecture and is written with performance in
>   mind. It is usually bound by the speed of the network, effectively
>   turning performance into a non-issue. You get to focus on how your web
>   applications work and you can allow yourself, to some degree, to care
>   less about performance and scalability.

And this [Blog](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/getting-started-with/9781491972212/ch01.html) about varnish cache is a "MUST READ" for someone that is interested on applying varnish (in this case you ).

Answer (score 0):

Well, If your using varnish without SSL than its good to use.However it is not [compatible with the SSL](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/phk/ssl.html).

Also magento 2 documentation also spacify [under known issues](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/varnish/config-varnish.html) 
 . You have to consider this before using varnish cache

Comment: Varnish is *not incompatible* with SSL. It does not *support* SSL. Typically you would add nginx or other SSL capable software (e.g. hitch) for terminating SSL in front of Varnish. Open source Varnish does not ship with SSL support (thus requires aforementioned SSL terminators), where Varnish Plus supports SSL out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Varnish will help to improve the performance to reduce the loading time on the products page.

Magento 2 emits the necessary `Cache-Control` headers and ESI tags for Varnish cache, even in developer mode.